# ContentDialog when close window of app

Tags: uwp, windows-10

I would like when closing window of app, appaer a ContentDialog like on Edge.
Not exist a real event for closing window.
It's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this, although it is a known limitation of UWP that we will address in a future update.